# Jersy service not accepting gzip encoded request

Tags: java, jersey

Hi this is the web method to receive JSON and response JSON but the problem is this web method doesn't accept the gzip encoded request so how to make it to gzip acceptable web method?

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/pdf2doc")
public RPDOC postDocument(DPDF dpdf){
}
```

DPDF is the class

```
public class DPDF{   
public String docid;
public String pdfdata;    
}
```

This the client code with gzip Content encoding and throw exeption

```
               String body = "{\"docid\": 1234, \"docdata\": \"test\"}";


               HttpEntity httpEntity =  EntityBuilder.create().setText(body)
                                        .setContentEncoding("gzip")
                                       .gzipCompress().build();

                 final String postUrl = serviceURL;
                 HttpUriRequest request = RequestBuilder.post(postUrl)
                                    .setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, 
                                        "application/json")
                                    .setHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, 
                                        "application/json")
                                    .setEntity(httpEntity)
                                    .build();

        String sResponse = null;

        try (CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
             CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request))
        {
            StatusLine sl = response.getStatusLine();

                int statusCode = sl.getStatusCode();
                System.out.println("HTTP Status: " + statusCode);

               HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
               if (entity != null)
               {
                sResponse = EntityUtils.toString(entity).trim();
                System.out.println("HTTP Body:\n" + sResponse);

                EntityUtils.consumeQuietly(entity);
               }
               }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            request.abort();
            throw e;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Gzip format, it looks like you are trying to upload a file to REST API. In that case, your API should consume multipart request. Check [this](https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/file-upload-example-in-jersey/) example

Comment: Vikas - i can post the file data to the data without any issue, everything working fine, if i  set "Content-Encoding" : gzip, the request is crashed and getting this error "java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error"

Comment: I think there is some problem in your client code, can you paste your client code

Comment: Viakas - if i set "Content-Encoding : gzip" with client then should i change anything in my Jersey service to accept compressed JSON ?

Comment: Vikas - just updated the question with client code